# Dynamical options adding to select element not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, materialize

I have read all the similar questions provided by SO, but no one is solving my issue.

I have the following html:

```
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">



<form action="" id="myForm">
   <div class="input-field col s12 l6">
       <select id="myselectid" name="myselectname">
       </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 l6">
     <button id="" class="btn blue" type="submit"> submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I'd need to populate the select element with values of the key "name" of a JSON file.

myJSON

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "test.txt",
      "format": "txt",
      "size": 92502
    },
    {
      "name": "mini-test.txt",
      "format": "txt",
      "size": 64855
   }
]
```

myJS

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   $.getJSON(myJSON, function(data){
      var select = document.getElementById("myselectid");
      $.each(data.resources, function(i, field){
        select.add(new Option(field.name, field.name));
      });
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.sidenav').sidenav();
     $('select').formSelect();
  });
 </script>
```

I get a drop down menu with empty default value. By clicking the arrow to expand the menu I get only the option `"test.txt"`.

The odd thing is that the Firefox inspector shows the expected html in grey color

```
<select id="myselectid" name="myselectname" tabindex=-1>
  <option value="test.txt">test.txt</option>
  <option value="mini-test.txt">mini-test.txt</option>
</select>
```

What is going on?

Any help is really welcome..

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
The issue is caused by the materialize framework. I was initialising the select element BEFORE adding options to it. Check my answer for details.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me when I recreated it. The only difference was that I didn't actually load the resources externally, just defined the JSON in code - but I can't see how that would impact the HTML if it's arriving in the format you say it is. Options all displayed fine. So the problem would logically seem to be somewhere else. Is this really the only code you have? Do you get any console errors? Maybe worth showing your full code.

Comment: @Toby: thank you for your comment. No problem to show the entire code but I've just verified that the issue is caused by the materialize framework. If I comment it out I get an awful dropdown menu that is actually showing all the options. Any idea on how to fix this

Comment: So something in materialize breaks your code? That's a pretty broad question. My guess would be that you are applying the materialize library's select decoration before your json loads, and it isn't picking up the options you add. But without seeing your actual code, it's almost impossible to do anything except guess.

Comment: @Toby you are correct. Solved the OP's issue over at the M Gitter channel. The M Select needs to be initialized AFTER the dynamic population. Hopefully she'll post the solution :)

Comment: @SeanDoherty thanks for the confirmation. It's a common problem with using frameworks which operate on the DOM. Sounds like you provide outstanding support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved thanks to Sean Doherty at the Materialize Gitter channel.

The problem occurred because I was initialising the M select element BEFORE the dynamic population.

Here follows the correct

myJS

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   $.getJSON(myJSON, function(data){
      var select = document.getElementById("myselectid");
      $.each(data.resources, function(i, field){
        select.add(new Option(field.name, field.name));
      });
      // init select element after collecting the option values
      M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select'));
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.sidenav').sidenav();
     // do not init select here because the dyn population is not done yet
     //$('select').formSelect();
  });
 </script>
```